# MySQL: Aggregation the similar value fields from Table 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a query from two tables, Table 1 contains a contract between the company and the customer.
Table 2 contains a statement payments.
What I want to do is: assembling late payments from Table 2 values, so that the value of each batch 250$ and displayed as follows:

```
____________________________________
Client  |   late payments  |  total
____________________________________
John    |        2         |    500 (250*2)
____________________________________
```

Table2 like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYR8T.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. See if you can update your question with a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried. Here are some help pages to get you started: [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

First use `Concat` for create date and `cast` string as date and compare  with paydate at last use `group by` and calculate `sum` or `count` of late paid

```
SELECT contract_id,count(contract_id) late_payments,sum(paid) total FROM `table` 
where cast(Concat(year.'-',month,'-',day) as date) < paydate
Group by contract_id
```